# Bash compare two different files and get non-matching lines from second

Tags: bash, awk, sed, grep

I know how to compare two files and get the matching line result from 2nd ( file_2.txt) file using `awk`

```
Run Method : $awk -F"," 'NR==FNR{a[$1];next} $1 in a' file_1.txt file_2.txt

$cat file_1.txt
95335df46cfdb345c0214296e0043c00,5,M,N
a0af947a85e6895dab70eaec136cfed2,4,P,Q

$cat file_2.txt
77f673137c17b4b0405d13060e9715a3,5,X,Y
874d51610c15975c82c081aba0b096c3,5,A,M
95335df46cfdb345c0214296e0043c00,5,M,N
```

How can i compare the second file `file_2.txt` against the first `file_1.txt` and get the non-matched lines from the second file ( `file_2.txt` ) ?

Any suggestions please ?

Comment: just use `!($1 in a)`

Comment: or `grep -v -f  file1.txt file2.txt` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$ awk -F"," 'NR==FNR{a[$1];next} !($1 in a)' file_1.txt file_2.txt
77f673137c17b4b0405d13060e9715a3,5,X,Y
874d51610c15975c82c081aba0b096c3,5,A,M
```